# Turn ConnectApi.FeedElement.body into string

Tags: apex

I have retrieved a FeedElement by it's postId. I now want to test that the feed.body is a certain value. FeedElement.Body is of type FeedBody. [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_feed_body.htm) is the documentation for FeedBody which as you can see doesn't say much. What is the best way to turn a FeedBody into a string ?

```
ConnectApi.FeedElement testPost = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(),postId);
String testMessage = vct.getTestMessage();
System.assertEquals(testMessage,testPost.body);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FeedBody` is a concrete subclass of [`ConnectApi.AbstractMessageBody`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_abstractMessageBody.htm).

*That* class has a property `text` that's inherited by `FeedBody`, which you should be able to access and make assertions against. It's of type `String`. (Unless you want to iterate through the message segments to validate a user mention or something like that).